# Need to understand the end of Karatsuba algorithm running time proof

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I cannot understand the end of Karatsuba algorithms running time proof.
Initially we have formula
$$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2}) + rn$$ 
if n > 1
$$T(n) = r $$
if n = 1
, where r is a constant.

We assumed that $n=2^k$

$$T(2^k) = 3T(2^{k-1}) + r2^k$$
Then we recursively proceeded up to base case.
In the end we got 
$$= 3^kr + 2^kr * \frac{\frac {3}{2} ^ k - 1}{\frac{3}{2} - 1}$$

The next lines of proof I did not understand:
$$T(n) <= d3^k$$
d is constant
$$n = 2^k$$
$$3^k = x$$
$$log_3x = k = log_2n = \frac{log_3n}{log_32}$$
$$log_3x = log_3n^{1.59}$$
$$x = n^{1.59}$$

---

Can someone please explain how we got $\frac{log_3n}{log_32}$ and $log_3x = log_3n^{1.59}$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n = 2^k$  by multiplying with $\log_2x$ in both sides we have :

$\log_2xn= \log_2x2^k$

$\log_2xn=k$

similarly $k=\log_3x$

this might be helpful to understand the properties of logarithms:

http://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/math/webtexts/numb17.htm